# AWS connection between two EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two EC2 instance in same region. One is Elastic Beanstalk server hosting my application using Tomcat 7, other has Mongodb running. When I am trying to access Mongodb from Tomcat using public-ip:port it is unable to connect. Could you please let me know the changes to be done so that both the servers can communicate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the Security Group which contains the Tomcat 7 Elastic Beanstalk instance and allow the Mongo EC2 instance public ip and port.

You might need to edit the Mongo EC2 instance security group to allow communication from the tomcat host.

Comment: Could you please guide me how to do this??

Comment: @Debopam Go to MongoDB Instance search for security group click on Edit button add InBound Rule add custom tcp with port 27017 for Private ip of Webservice instance. That's it. If any issue ping me.